# Could not parse query, Fusion Tables API Advanced Visualization Sample code

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization, google-fusion-tables

From the example given in fusion tables API advanced visualization sample code, I managed to come up with a map and the legend. However, the column chart is not displaying. "Could not parse query" is the error which is being displayed. What could be the problem?

This is my code of my column chart.

```
      function drawVisualization(County) {
    google.visualization.drawChart({
      containerId: "visualization",
      dataSourceUrl: "http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=",
      query: "SELECT Environment,'BoysPupils','GirlsPupils','FemaleTeachers','MaleTeachers','BoardingPupils' " +
          "FROM 1eC4sIAgVXfFj01mOM2cDiyW2nly7TcFeIXj1G3s WHERE County = '" + County + "'",
      chartType: "ColumnChart",
      options: {
        title: County,
        height: 400,
        width: 400
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using 2 wrong column-names: `'BoysPupils','GirlsPupils'`
it has to be `'BoyPupils','GirlPupils'`